# Laravel css is accessible but browsers not loading it

Tags: php, laravel

When i try to run my app locally css and other static files is accessible  but browser don't load them.
[image]

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/core.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: What is your browser logging in the console?

Comment: what is the output of `{{ URL::asset('assets/css/core.css') }}` ?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/assets/css/core.css

Comment: And can you open that file from the generated url?

Comment: yes i can open this file and see css code

Comment: Clear your browser cookies & Cache and try again.

Comment: tried but it does nothing still same

Comment: open in your browser localhost:8000/assets/css/core.css , bet there will be not css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
{{ URL::asset('assets/css/core.css') }}
```

replace with:

```
 {{ url('/assets/css/core.css') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/core.css') }}"/>
```

Note I have dropped the 'URL' at the beginning of asset, I am assuming you have your URL in your .ENV and it might not be pointing to your localhost.

It's easier to just drop the URL, it wont cause you issues moving forward.